# In R I want to add a count variable in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a this dataframe in R:

```
V1
A
A
C
C
C
```

I want add a variable like this:

```
V1 V2
A  1
A  2
C  1
C  2
C  3
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(V1) %>% mutate(V2 = seq_along(V1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer:

```
> df <- data.frame(V1 = c('A','A','C','C','C'))
> df
  V1
1  A
2  A
3  C
4  C
5  C
> df %>% group_by(V1) %>% mutate(v2 = row_number())
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   V1 [2]
  V1       v2
  <fct> <int>
1 A         1
2 A         2
3 C         1
4 C         2
5 C         3
>
```